# Why does every JPEG I export from Lightroom 5 have Adobe RGB embedded no matter what color profile I select?

Tags: lightroom, color-management

I have just noticed that lightroom 5.7 exports every jpeg with AdobeRGB profile embedded, no matter what profile I select in export dialog box, Anyone has an idea why?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this in 5.7.1 - it's working as expected for me. Can you let us know what OS you are using, and how you are determining the embedded profile of the exported JPEG files please? Also are you using the very latest version (i.e. 5.7.1)?

Comment: Have you try to create new export profile with exact setting you need?

Comment: It might help if you described the exact process, because there are several ways to get jpeg photo out of LR. Are you using soft proof to Adobe RGB?

Answer (score 1):

Here is proof it works. First screenshot is the export dialog the second is file properties of the exported jpeg
http://www.evernote.com/l/AIJHZi_JXDFGfaasLICfpOKkf-uxt2gNpBs/

http://www.evernote.com/l/AILGtLEgJ3NEaZ6IEnoXHKqkXrNqLoGFQyQ/

By any chance did you change the colour space and forget to rt click the preset name and click on update with current settings